# Scaling of validation data in supervised ML algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, normal-distribution

I have written a classification algorithm in Python. It satisfies to Scikit-Learn's API. Given labeled data `X, y`, I would like to train my algorithm on this data in the following way:

- `X, y` are split into `X_aux, y_aux` and `X_test, y_test`.
- `X_aux, y_aux` are split into `X_train, y_train` and `X_val, y_val`.

Then, using Scikit-Learn, I define a Pipeline which is the concatenation of a StandardScaler (for feature normalization) and my model. Eventually, the pipeline is trained and evaluated as follows:

```
pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('clf', Model())])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data = (X_val, y_val))
pred_proba = pipe.predict_proba(X_test)
score = roc_auc_score(y_test, pred_proba)
```

The `fit` method of `Model` accepts a `validation_data` parameter to monitor progress during training and possibly avoid overfitting. To this aim, at each iteration, the `fit` method prints the model loss on training data `(X_train, y_train)` (training loss) and model loss on validation data `(X_val, y_val)` (validation loss). In addition to validation loss, I also would like the `fit` method to return ROC AUC score on validation data. My question is the following :

> Shall `X_val` be normalized with the scaler of the pipeline before it is used to compute validation ROC AUC score during training ? Also, in this code, only `X_train` is normalized by the scaler. Should I do `X_aux = scaler.fit_transform(X_aux)` instead and *then* split into train/validation ?

---

I apologize in advance for my question is very naive. I confess I got confused.
I think that `X_val` should be normalized. The way I see it is that the few lines of code above are equivalent to:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
clf = Model()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)                                                                                                                                                              
clf.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data = (X_val, y_val))          
#    During `fit`, at each iteration, we would have:
#    train_loss = loss(X_train, y_train)
#    validation_loss = loss(X_val, y_val)
#    pred_proba_val = predict_proba(X_val, y_val)                   (*)
#    roc_auc_val = roc_auc_score(y_val, pred_proba_val)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
pred_proba = clf.predict_proba(X_test)                              (**)
score = roc_auc_score(y_test, pred_proba)
```

In line (*) the predict_proba method is called on unnormalized data whereas it is called on normalized data on line (**). This is why I believe that `X_val` should be normalized. Still I am not sure whether my thinking is correct.

Comment: Yes you are correct. You should do `X_val = scaler.transform(X_val)`.

Comment: Also, never fit the data first and split after as you wanted to do in `X_aux = scaler.fit_transform(X_aux)`. This causes leakage of information to the model and may give you skewed (better) results, then they actually are.